# How to send activation email/code using cartalyst sentinel using laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

I want to send activation email/code to their emails during signup procedure but I am unable to find suitable answer that help me to complete my work.

This is my controller method where i am saving user data into my database using sentinel.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate($request->all());
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Here i want to sent activation email/code to their email when user signup.

Your any help would be highly appreciated!

```
                     public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $user = Sentinel::register($request->all());
    $activation = Activation::create($user);

    $this->sendEmail($user, $activation->code);
    return redirect('/');
}

private function sendEmail($user,$code)
{
    Mail::send('emails.activation',[

            'user' => $user,
            'code' => $code
    ], function($message) use ($user){
        $message->to($user->email);
        $message->subject("Hello $user->first_name,
        activate your account.");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code 
use MAIL namespace in your controller moreover don't forget to create email.verify blade in your application path resources\views\email and create smtp detail in .env file.

*MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io

MAIL_PORT=2525

MAIL_USERNAME=username

MAIL_PASSWORD=password

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=your_email@address.com

MAIL_FROM_NAME=YOURNAME

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null*

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {
        $verification_code = 111111;   // create random number & save it to db ;
        $user = Sentinel::registerAndActivate($request->all());
        return redirect('/');

        $subject = "Please verify your email address.";
        Mail::send('email.verify', ['name' => $user->name, 'verification_code' => $verification_code],
            function ($mail) use ($user, $subject) {
                $mail->from(getenv('FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS'), "YOUR APPLICATION NAME");
                $mail->to($user->email, $user->name);
                $mail->subject($subject);
            });
    }
```

this is your email.verify blade :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div>
    Hi {{ $name }},
    <br>
    Thank you for creating an account with us.
    <br>
    Your verification code : <b>{{$verification_code}}</b>
    <br/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that looks perfect . you may go had while using this .